# Kendo Template, address certain element of json array

Tags: json, kendo-ui

Hi I'm trying to programm my first app in Icentium. I want to store wisdoms in a json array. Depending on your level you get a new wisdom. Unfortunately I don't know why it is shwoing the whole json array.

This is the lessons.js

```
(function(global) {  
var LessonsViewModel,
    app = global.app = global.app || {};

LessonsViewModel = kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend({
    lessonsDataSource: null,

    init: function () {
        var that = this,
            dataSource;

        kendo.data.ObservableObject.fn.init.apply(that, []);

        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "data/lessons/lessons.json",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        });

        that.set("lessonsDataSource", dataSource);           
    }        
});  

app.lessonsService = {
    viewModel: new LessonsViewModel()
};
```

This is the view

```
        <!--Lessons-->
    <div id="tabstrip-lesson" 
         data-role="view"  
         data-title="Lektion" 
         data-model="app.lessonsService.viewModel">

        <div class="lesson">

            <div class="separator">
                <div class="dark"></div>
                <div class="light"></div>
            </div>

            <ul class="forecast-list" 
                data-role="listview" 
                data-bind="source: lessonsDataSource" 
                data-template="lessons-template"><!-- Das unten stehende Kendo Template wird hier eingefügt-->
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    <!--Lessons Kendo Template für oben-->
    <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="lessons-template">
        <div>
            <h1>${dojoroom}</h1>
            <p>${text}</p><!-- Text aus Json File wird ausgelesen-->   
        </div>
    </script>
```

This is my json array:

```
[
{
    "dojoroom": "Dojo - First Room",
    "text": "Bla bla bla!"
},
{
    "dojoroom": "Dojo - Second Raum",
    "text": "More Bla"
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

So far what I tried according to the Kendo Documenation (http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource):

```
    LessonsViewModel = kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend({
    lessonsDataSource: null,

    init: function () {
        var that = this,
            dataSource;

        kendo.data.ObservableObject.fn.init.apply(that, []);

        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "data/lessons/lessons.json",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        });

        that.set("lessonsDataSource", dataSource.at(0));           
    }        
});
```

But this doesn't show anything at all. I also tried dataSource[0] and the same approaches in the view.

And `dataSource.fetch(function(){
                var dojo = dataSource.at(0);
                that.set("lessonsDataSource", dojo);
            });`